# fine-grained undo

Tags: undo

How to make `M-x undo` more fine-grained or sensitive?

**Example**:
say, I wrote:

> foo (bar baz) ()

then I `M-x undo` and receive:

> foo (bar

but what I want to get after this undo is:

> foo (bar baz)

Comment: You can restrict undoing by marking the appropriate part of the buffer before calling `undo`.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you want is readily possible.  Here's a good write up of how the Emacs `undo` command works: https://web.archive.org/web/20180518040652/https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6yzwic/how_emacs_undo_works/  Also, be wary of `undo-tree`.  It has a bug in it which loses the history (quite frequently in my experience): https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/issues/1074

Comment: See the emacs [documentation for undo](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Undo.html). It states that "Consecutive character insertion commands are usually grouped together into a single undo record, to make undoing less tedious." So the behavior depends on what you typed. If you typed `baz) ()` all consecutively, then those would be grouped together and all undone at once. The manual doesn't indicate any way to change that, although perhaps there are packages that will help (I don't know).

Comment: I guess my question is: why do you expect to get `foo (bar baz)`? What is the sequence of actions you've taken prior to issuing the `undo` command?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 interesting, thanks for this tip!

Comment: @MTS because I don't like the behaviour and it's emacs what I'm using :)

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I was trying to ask you to describe exactly what happened before you used `undo`. According to the documentation, if you sequentially typed the sequence of characters `f o o <SPC> ( b a r <SPC> b a z ) <SPC> ( )` and then issued the `undo` command, it should remove the entire thing. So I was asking what made you expect that only the final two parens would be removed. Perhaps when you said "what I expect after this undo" you really meant "what I want after this undo"? Anyway, disabling amalgamation as suggested in the accepted answer is probably your best bet.

Comment: @MTS expect -> want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like to do two things with undo.  I turn off the amalgamation stuff (which by doing so permits undo one keystroke at at time); and, I get rid of the timer (because timers affect performance and drive me absolutely bonkers, unless they are idle-timers.

Alternatively, you can modify `undo-auto-amalgamate` which is hard coded at 20 and set it to a lesser/greater amount.

```lisp
(when (timerp undo-auto-current-boundary-timer)
  (cancel-timer undo-auto-current-boundary-timer))

(fset 'undo-auto--undoable-change
      (lambda () (add-to-list 'undo-auto--undoably-changed-buffers (current-buffer))))

(fset 'undo-auto-amalgamate 'ignore)
```

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I want.  Any idea why it wouldn't work with Doom Emacs?